# Sequence of continuous linear functionals over a sequence of Hilbert spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $H_n$ be a sequence of complex Hilbert spaces such that $H_{n+1}\subsetneq H_n$ and $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty H_n=\{v_0\}$

Let $T_1:H_1\to \mathbb C$ be a continuous linear functional such that $T_1(v_0)=0$

Let, for each $n \in \mathbb N$, $T_n:H_n\to\mathbb C$ the continuous linear functionals obtained by restriction of $T_1$ to $H_n$

I would like to know if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lVert T_n \rVert = 0$

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Then you can call $v_0=0$ because there is no other choice for $v_0$ and drop the assumption that $T_1(v_0) =0$ since this is automatically fulfilled.

Comment: ok thanks @LeBtz

Comment: Do we have $H_n \subset H_1$?

Comment: yes @PiotrBenedysiuk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your statement is true even for reflexive<sup>1</sup> Banach spaces instead of Hilbert spaces.

Let $x_n\in H_n$ with $\|x_n\| = 1$ and $|T_n(x_n)| = \|T_n\|$. Such an element exists because $H_n$ is reflexive<sup>2</sup>.

Let us first assume that $H_1$ is separable.

Now, because the closed unit ball is weakly compact and $H_1$ is separable there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k$ of $(x_n)_n$ which converges weakly to some $x\in H_1$. Because each $H_n$ is closed and convex in $H_1$, it is also weakly closed. For each $n\in\mathbb N$, almost all $x_{n_k}$ are an element of $H_n$, therefore $x\in H_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, which yields $x=0$.

But now, $x_{n_k}\to 0$ weakly which yields $\|T_{n_k}\| = |T_{n_k}(x_{n_k})| = |T_1(x_{n_k})|\to 0$. Since the sequence of $\|T_n\|$ is decreasing, this yields the claim.

If $H_1$ is not separable then replace $H_n$ with $X_n := H_n\cap \overline{\operatorname{span}}(\{x_i: i\in\mathbb N\})$. The restriction of $T_n$ from $H_n$ to $X_n$ preserves the norm and $X_1$ is separable.

<sup>1</sup>I don't know if reflexivity is necessary but my proof relies on it. It is definitely not true for each Banach space as pointed out in the comments. Thanks for the example.

<sup>2</sup> We don't need reflexivity at this point it just makes the proof more simple. It would suffice to have $|T_n(x_n)|\geq \frac 12\|T_n\|$ which we always find.

Comment: Reflexivity might be necessary. For a non-reflexive case, consider   $H_0=C[0,1].$ Let $\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]=\{q_n:n\in \mathbb N \}.$  Let $H_n=\{f\in H_0: j\leq n\implies f(q_j)=0\}.$  Let  $T_0(f)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$ and $T_n=T_0|_{H_n}.$  Then $\|T_n\|=1$  for all $n.$

Comment: Thanks for the example, I included a note in my answer. @user254665

Comment: @user254665: In your example, why is $\| T_n\|=1$? It's not obvious to me.

Comment: @Jose . With the $\sup$ norm:    $Q_n=\{q_j: j\leq n\}$ is finite. So for any $r\in (0,1)$ we can find continuous $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ with $f(Q_n)=\{0\}$ and such that the measure of $ \{x: f(x)\ne 1\}$ is less than $r.$  So  $f\in H_n$ with $\|f\|=1$ and  $T_n(f)>1-r.$