# Limit of a sequence of norms of functionals linear on a sequence of Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H_n$ be a sequence of complex Hilbert spaces such that $H_{n+1}\subsetneq H_n$ and $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty H_n=\operatorname{span}\{v_0\}$

Let $T_1:H_1\to \mathbb C$ be a continuous linear functional such that $T_1(v_0)=0$

Let, for each $n \in \mathbb N$, $T_n:H_n\to\mathbb C$ the continuous linear functionals obtained by restriction of $T_1$ to $H_n$

I would like to know if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lVert T_n \rVert = 0$

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Does $H_{n+1}$ carry the subspace topology induced by $H_n$, or can it have a strictly finer topology?

Comment: @DanielFischer  $H_{n+1}$ carries the subspace topology induced by $H_n$

Comment: a previous similiar question of mine is here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078269/sequence-of-continuous-linear-functionals-over-a-sequence-of-hilbert-spaces the difference is that now the intersections of $H_n$ is $span\{v_0\}$

Comment: There's essentially no difference to that question. Let $A = \operatorname{span} \{v_0\}$, and $B = A^{\perp}$. Then every $H_n$ has the orthogonal decomposition $H_n = A \oplus (B\cap H_n)$, and since $T_1(v_0) = 0$, you're looking at $S_1 = T_1\lvert_B$ and $S_n = T_1\lvert_{B\cap H_n}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer so $\lim_{n \to \infty}||T_n||=0$ now too?

Comment: Yes. (Because $T_1(v_0) = 0$ implies $\lVert T_n\rVert = \lVert S_n\rVert$.)

Comment: ok @DanielFischer thanks you so much

Comment: Strange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078269/sequence-of-continuous-linear-functionals-over-a-sequence-of-hilbert-spaces

Comment: @AndréS. what's strage?